# Weak headphone volume during playback through Mbox 2 interface

Tags: homerecording, audacity

I bought an Mbox 2 off of Ebay, which I'm trying to use to record some demos. I'm using it with Audacity on Linux, via the JACK sound server. When I listen through the headphones (via the Mbox 2 headphone socket) while I'm playing something on my guitar, it sounds great; however, if I record it in Audacity and then play it back through the Mbox 2 headphones, the signal seems a lot weaker. I can hear it if I really crank up the Mbox 2 headphone volume knob to max, but it's a bit of a nuisance and it's going to make it difficult to monitor properly while I'm recording. The playback sounds fine if I put it through my PC's built-in sound card.

I'm just wondering if anyone else has experienced anything similar with this interface, or has an idea of what the problem might be? I have the output volume set at max in Audacity, so perhaps there is something not set correctly in JACK? Is there some way I can boost the signal?

Comment: This question might get better exposure - and therefore increase its chance of being answered - if it was moved to https://sound.stackexchange.com/ because it is about technical audio quality rather than musical composition.

Comment: tbh, it would be better asked on the manufacturer's site. It requires too much specific hardware/software knowledge.... & the OS isn't even mentioned.

Comment: @Tetsujin actually, I had mentioned I was using Audacity on Linux. It is quite specific, although Todd Wilcox gave the right answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely explanation is the **Mix** control in the front of the mBox 2 is too far to the left. Try turning the Mix control all the way to the right for playback.

See: http://akmedia.digidesign.com/support/docs/Mbox_2_Basics_Guide_25679.pdf (PDF download)

Comment: Yes, this is exactly right. I hadn't realized what the mix control was for. Many thanks!